# Mounting raid5 disks without one of raid's member

Tags: linux, hard-drive, raid, mount, software-raid

I have to read data from disks, which are raid5 members. I'm wondering if there is posibility to read data from those disks somehow, but one of those disks is just broken. I was trying to mount some partitions, but without results. It says:

> ... assembled from 1 drive - not enought to start the array.

Can i repair/mount those raid5 disks somehow ?

EDIT1: Added lsblk result

```
 root@ubunciak:~# lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda       8:0    0   2,7T  0 disk  
├─sda1    8:1    0     4G  0 part  
├─sda2    8:2    0   512M  0 part  
│ └─md1   9:1    0 511,4M  0 raid1 
└─sda3    8:3    0   2,7T  0 part  
sdb       8:16   0 232,9G  0 disk  
├─sdb1    8:17   0 230,9G  0 part  /
├─sdb2    8:18   0     1K  0 part  
└─sdb5    8:21   0     2G  0 part  [SWAP]
sdc       8:32   0   2,7T  0 disk  
├─sdc1    8:33   0     4G  0 part  
├─sdc2    8:34   0   512M  0 part  
│ └─md1   9:1    0 511,4M  0 raid1 
└─sdc3    8:35   0   2,7T  0 part  
sdd       8:48   0   2,7T  0 disk  
├─sdd1    8:49   0     4G  0 part  
│ └─md0   9:0    0     4G  0 raid1 
├─sdd2    8:50   0   512M  0 part  
│ └─md1   9:1    0 511,4M  0 raid1 
└─sdd3    8:51   0   2,7T  0 part
```

Comment: You’re not *missing* a drive, you *have* a drive. That’s at least one short of a working array, assuming a three-disk array.

Comment: What should i do then ?

Comment: Mourn your data. Unless at least one additional drive makes a miraculous comeback, it is gone.

Comment: Sorry, but i would need some explanations. From what you wrote, i understood that i need to mount additional fourth HDD and recreate array somehow ?

Answer (score 2):

A RAID5 array can tolerate a single drive failure. It consists of at least 3 drives.

You get this error message:

> ... assembled from 1 drive - not enought to start the array.

It says there is only one drive left. This isn’t enough to start a RAID5 array, even in degraded state.

Assuming a 3-drive array, you need at least one more drive to start the array. Of course, this drive has to be a member of the array, not just any drive.

If you do not have at least N-1 working drives from your N-drive array, your data is forever gone.

Comment: I've tried `mdadm --assemble --run /dev/md/md3 /dev/sd[bcd]3` but it tells: `mdadm: /dev/md/md3 assembled from 2 drives - not enought to start the array.`. That's mean it's over ?

Comment: Basically. How many drives did the array originally consist of? Are you sure the partitions you specified are correct?

Comment: We have NAS machine which using 4 HDD's. It means that array consists of 4 drives (i think). Im sure that specified partitions are correct.

Comment: Well so the partitions weren’t correct after all. Try `sd[acd]3`.

Answer (score 1):

Disconnect and reconnect all drives. It appears only 1 of 4 is currently detectable. It is extremely unlikely that 3 out of 4 drives suddenly fail, so it looks like a connectivity problem. Reconnect all the drives and access the NAS to check what's detected. Make sure they're correctly powered and connected.

Comment: `lsblk` shows all of specified disks

Comment: And what does it show ? Post a screenshot if possible. Your disk controller may have switched from RAID to normal AHCI mode. That can also explain what's happening.

Comment: Does it matter if one disk is connected via USB dock station ?

Comment: Yes, please connect all disks in the same way.